Can the potential of a point charge be considered one-dimensional?
It is well known that,take infinity as 0 potential,the potential at position r of a point charge q placed at the origin is
$$V = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0}\frac{q}{r}$$
it satisfies three dimensional Laplace equation
$$\nabla^2V = 0$$
Because the Laplacian in spherical coordinates is
$$\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}$$
Since V does not have a $\theta$ and $\phi$ component,taking partial derivative of V with respect to r gives$\frac{1}{r^2}$.Multiplied by the $r^2$ gives a constant and therefore 0 when taking partial derivative again.
But, because the potential has only one variable r,can we think of it as one dimensional? Consider placing the charge at the origin and measure the potential at each point x on the x axes,we get:
$$V =  \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0}\frac{q}{x}$$
Then if we apply the one dimensional Laplacian to V, it is obvious that the result is not 0, since the Laplacian in one dimension is simply second derivative with x.
I think maybe we can't consider it as one dimensional,but I can't explain very clearly why.What is the difference between having only one variable and one dimensional? Or maybe this is not the point,so what is it? Appreciated!

It isn't one dimensional but it is spherically symmetric.

Mathematically, we can indeed think of it as being one-dimensional, since it depends on only one variable. Therefore you can describe its full behavior by plotting it along a line. But the potential still has a value in all of three-dimensional space, and so it is physically not one-dimensional.
Your math, however, has a different problem: the radius coordinate $r$ cannot be freely exchanged with the cartesian coordinate $x$, since in 3D space we have the identity
$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$
Thus, being one-dimensional in the spherical coordinate system is not the same as being one-dimensional in the cartesian coordinate system.
